# When can $H = H_0 + \lambda V$ be perturbed in a weak interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Consider a finite-dimensional free Hamiltonian $H_0$, interaction $V$ and dimensionless coupling $\lambda \ll 1$ so that
$$
H = H_0 + \lambda V \ .
$$

My question is, when is one allowed to perturb in $\lambda$?

For example, for some $\omega > 0$ and $\nu \in \mathbb{C}$ (both with units of energy), if we let
$$
H = \left[ \begin{matrix} \omega & \lambda v \\ \lambda v^{\ast} & - \omega \end{matrix} \right]
$$
Then there it's easy to tell when (non-degenerate) perturbation theory applies: the energy eigenvalues of $H$ are exactly $\pm \sqrt{ \omega^2 + \lambda^2 |\nu|^2 }$, and if we let $\omega \gg \lambda |\nu|$, then of the course the perturbative series for the eigenvalues are $\pm \omega \left[ 1 + \dfrac{\lambda^2|v|^2}{2\omega^2} - \dfrac{\lambda^4|v|^4}{8\omega^4} + \ldots \right]$.

In this case it's simple to see that the condition $\omega \gg \lambda |\nu|$ is needed to apply non-degenerate perturbation theory. Of course, if this condition fails the series might not converge (like if you pick $\lambda |\nu| = 2 \omega$, for example) --- and you shouldn't be applying perturbation theory.

Is there a way to more generally understand when you are allowed to apply perturbation theory? Most quantum texts simply say, let $V$ be a "weak" interaction and don't really specify what this means. I find this unsatisfying.

Could it mean:

$\bullet$ $\det(H_0) \gg \det(\lambda V)$?

$\bullet$ The size of the eigenvalues of $H_0$ are $\gg$ the size of the eigenvalues of $\lambda V$?

$\bullet$ (probably) something else?

**P.S.** It also can't be correct to just say that $\lambda$ needs to be small: In the above example you can set $\lambda = 10^{-10}$ if you'd like, but if you make $|\nu| = 10^{+12} \omega$ then you're screwed (since $\lambda \nu = 100 \omega$).

Answer (score 2):

The perturbative expansion is usually in terms of ratios of the type 
$\frac{\hbox{off diagonal elements}}{\hbox{energy differences}}$ so the actual size of the eigenvalues of $H_0$ does not matter: in particular, if two eigenvalues of $H_0$ are "close" so the above ratio is "large" then perturbation theory is useless.

At issue is thus the size of such ratios and how many terms you want to keep.  This is much like a power series where you may or may not be happy with truncating the series after only one term, depending on the accuracy required.

See also [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306890/relation-between-perturbation-theory-and-taylor-expansion-in-qm) for additional discussion.